Were Soldiers from Osaka Considered Bad/Unlucky Troops?
In the book "Rising Sun, Tumbling Bear" about the Russo-Japanese war the author states that, "since time immemorial, Osaka soldiers had had a reputation for failing." The authors says the Japanese 4th (Osaka) Division was called the "Unlucky Fourth" by the rest of the Japanese army for that reason.
Is there any truth to this, and if so, why were soldiers from Osaka considered "bad"?  The "Time Immemorial" part of the quote makes me think they were considered inferior troops for centuries, but if there's something more recent to the Russo-Japanese war (like Osakan soldiers performing poorly in the Sino-Japanese war 1894-1895) I would accept that as a reason for the author to make the comment. Likewise I'd be interested if they were considered "bad" only by the Japanese, or if this reputation had spread to other powers.
It's fairly common for soldiers from certain regions/certain units to be considered "bad" but my research into this topic is hampered by WWII Japan being so overwhelming on the internet, knowing very little of Japanese military history pre-1900, and knowing no Japanese!

The author appears to be exaggerating, although it's unclear if it's due to misinformation or for rhetorical effect. The "Unlucky 4th" was activated in 1881, originating from the Osaka Garrison (1871).
You'll notice a number of other Osakan divisions listed in this resource, but only the 4th is singled out as particularly bad. Perhaps it is because 4 is an unlucky number, which would explain people not wanting to join it, and the division being under-strength and under-equipped as a result.

Thanks! I don't think it's for rhetorical effect. He seems pretty plain spoken, if perhaps overly eloquent in his battlefield descriptions at times, throughout the rest of the book. I forgot 4 was unlucky in Japanese and that would certainly account for the nickname even if the rest was wholly untrue!
